# How to make UIView autoheight based on a UILabel inside of it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm trying to make a `UIView` size his height depending on his `UILabel` inside of it. I've tried:

```
UIView *descriptionView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(marginX, currentY+marginYbetweenBlocks, widthOfBlock, 100)];
descriptionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UILabel *descriptionLabelBody = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(marginXforBody, marginYforBody, widthOfBody, 20)];
descriptionLabelBody.text = ShopWithDatas.description;
descriptionLabelBody.numberOfLines = 0;
[descriptionLabelBody sizeToFit];
descriptionLabelBody.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

[descriptionView addSubview:descriptionLabelBody];

[descriptionView sizeToFit];

[self.scroller addSubview:descriptionView];
```

But doesn't seem to work. Any idea ?

Comment: after You call sizeToFit, You could call  [descriptionView setFrame:CGRectMake(marginX, currentY+marginYbetweenBlocks, widthOfBlock, descriptionLabelBody.frame.size.height)];  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution of @GuntisTreulands worked:

```
UILabel *descriptionLabelBody = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(marginXforBody, marginYforBody, widthOfBody, 20)];
descriptionLabelBody.text = ShopWithDatas.description;
descriptionLabelBody.numberOfLines = 0;
[descriptionLabelBody sizeToFit];
descriptionLabelBody.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;


UIView *descriptionView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(marginX, currentY+marginYbetweenBlocks, widthOfBlock, 100)];
descriptionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[descriptionView setFrame:CGRectMake(marginX, currentY+marginYbetweenBlocks, widthOfBlock, descriptionLabelBody.frame.size.height)];

[descriptionView addSubview:descriptionLabelBody];

[self.scroller addSubview:descriptionView];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're creating your objects first initialise your label and then you can assign the height of the label as height of your container view. I have adjusted your code a little bit. Please see the following

```
UILabel *descriptionLabelBody = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(marginXforBody, marginYforBody, widthOfBody, 20)];
descriptionLabelBody.text = ShopWithDatas.description;
descriptionLabelBody.numberOfLines = 0;
[descriptionLabelBody sizeToFit];
descriptionLabelBody.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

UIView *descriptionView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(marginX, currentY+marginYbetweenBlocks, widthOfBlock, CGRectGetHeight(descriptionLabelBody.frame))];
descriptionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[descriptionView addSubview:descriptionLabelBody];

[self.scroller addSubview:descriptionView];
```

Comment: It won't adjust the size of the `descriptionView` accordingly to the `UILabel`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method:

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize;

maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(270, 10000);

NSAttributedString *attributedText =
[[NSAttributedString alloc]
 initWithString:newsTitle
 attributes:@
 {
 NSFontAttributeName: yourLbl.font
 }];
CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){270, 10000}
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           context:nil];
CGSize expectedTitleLabelSize = rect.size;
```

Now you can set the height of your view based on expectedTitleLabelSize.